# Two SUM()'s of the same column but grouped by different columns in the same select statement

Tags: sql

I have a table `employees` with `employee_id` and `department_of_employee`  and another table `phone_calls` that has columns `employee_id`, `date` and `number_of_phone_calls` on that day by given employee.

I would like to have a `SELECT`-statement that gives me a table the `employee_id`, the `department_id`, the number of total phone calls of employee (`calls_employee`) and the number of total phone calls per department of that employee (`calls_department`).

My approach till now is as follows:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.department_of_employee, SUM(p.number_of_phone_calls), SUM(<not_sure>)
FROM employees e, 
INNER JOIN phone_calls p
ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id;
```

My problem is, that I am not sure how to get both the total sum of phone calls per employee and the total
sum of phone calls per department in one `SELECT`-statement.
Currently I am only getting the total sum of phone calls per employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.department_of_employee, 
       SUM(p.number_of_phone_calls),
       SUM(SUM(p.number_of_phone_calls)) OVER (PARTITION BY e.department_of_employee)
FROM employees e INNER JOIN
     phone_calls p
    ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.department_of_employee;
```